# How does one adjust the width of the columns on a Gantt Chart

Tags: pgfgantt

I have managed to generate the following gantt chart:
[image]

However I want the columns to be wide enough so that my  `gantttitle`s fit into their columns and don't overflow, making it near impossible to read. This is a snippet of my current code:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid]{1}{20}

\gantttitle{\textsc{Quarter 2}}{10}
\gantttitle{\textsc{Quarter 3}}{10} \\
\gantttitle{Wk 1}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 2}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 3}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 4}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 5}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 6}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 7}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 8}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 9}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 10}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 1}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 2}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 3}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 4}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 5}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 6}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 7}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 8}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 9}{1}
\gantttitle{Wk 10}{1} \\
\ganttbar{Introduction}{1}{1} \\
\ganttbar{Literature Review}{2}{6} \\
\ganttbar{Prepare Proposal Structure}{3}{4}\\
\ganttbar{Proposal Due}{7}{7}
\ganttmilestone{}{7}\\
\ganttbar{Desktop application}{7}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Tablet application}{10}{15} \\
\ganttbar{Connecting applications}{9}{19} \\
\ganttbar{Final Draft for Review}{16}{18}\\
\ganttbar{Final Project Review}{19}{19}
\ganttmilestone{}{19}\\
\ganttbar{Final Report \& Presentation}{19}{20} 
\ganttmilestone{}{20}\\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{landscape}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `x unit` to set the width of a time slot

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid, x unit=1cm]{1}{20}

  \gantttitle{\textsc{Quarter 2}}{10}
  \gantttitle{\textsc{Quarter 3}}{10} \\
  \gantttitle{Wk 1}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 2}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 3}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 4}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 5}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 6}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 7}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 8}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 9}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 10}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 1}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 2}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 3}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 4}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 5}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 6}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 7}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 8}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 9}{1}
  \gantttitle{Wk 10}{1} \\
  \ganttbar{Introduction}{1}{1} \\
  \ganttbar{Literature Review}{2}{6} \\
  \ganttbar{Prepare Proposal Structure}{3}{4}\\
  \ganttbar{Proposal Due}{7}{7}
  \ganttmilestone{}{7}\\
  \ganttbar{Desktop application}{7}{12} \\
  \ganttbar{Tablet application}{10}{15} \\
  \ganttbar{Connecting applications}{9}{19} \\
  \ganttbar{Final Draft for Review}{16}{18}\\
  \ganttbar{Final Project Review}{19}{19}
  \ganttmilestone{}{19}\\
  \ganttbar{Final Report \& Presentation}{19}{20} 
  \ganttmilestone{}{20}\\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]